# Extract id along with count of other columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have four columns in my table

```
CUSTOMER, TRANSACTION(UNIQUE) PRODUCTA PRODUCTB
```

Product A or Product B is either 0 or 1 depending on the item bought. Both are not equal to 1 as each row corresponds to a transaction and it is either A or B.

Now I want to extract data such that each customer is listed along with the count of no of product A purchases and product B purchases he made.

```
select customer,count(PRODUCTA),count(PRODUCTB) from rm_saicharan_final6 group by customer
```

Its returning all the count including the 0s.

```
CUSTOMER   PRODUCTA   PRODUCTB
--------   --------   ---------
32444       209        209
```

But I want only the count having value=1 not all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use SUM as follows:

```
select customer,SUM(PRODUCTA),SUM(PRODUCTB) 
from rm_saicharan_final6 group by customer
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee7da/596

Comment: You are quite welcome. The aggregate function "Count" merely counts the number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this will work but, if it doesnt, it may help

```
select customer,count(PRODUCTA),count(PRODUCTB) from rm_saicharan_final6 group by customer where PRODUCTA>0 and PRODUCTB>0
```